# Как организовать контроль версий для многих модификаций одного проекта?

Tags: git

У меня есть основной код программы в `trunk` и есть множество модификаций этой программы, которые не накладываются друг на друга, а идут отдельными экземплярами этой программы, но при этом начальный функционал берут с неё.

Раньше обходился простым созданием репозитория для каждого отдельного экземпляра, но сейчас их стало много, и хочу просто добавлять их как ветки к основному коду программы вместо создания отдельного репозитория. Я в системе контроля версий слабо разбираюсь.

Поэтому и спрашиваю, можно ли так делать? Пробовал ещё subversion, но когда я сделал бранч, то он получил не первый номер ревизии, а тот, который был последний в trunk.

Comment: > По этому и спрашиваю, можно ли так делать? 

Можно, хотя это и не самый удобный вариант (в плане поддержки такой программы).

> Пробовал ещё subversion, но когда я сделал бранч, то он получил не первый номер ревизии, а тот, который был последний в trunk.

Само собой, нумерация сквозная. В гите у вас вообще не будет порядковых "номеров" как таковых.

Comment: Т.е. есть нечто "Б","В" являющеся форком "А"? 

Обновляется ли "А"?

Comment: @eicto, у меня аналогичный вопрос и ответ на ваш - да. Если можно, то и на примере SVN показать, как лучше, т.к. пока его используем.

Comment: @BOPOH, с svn я уже лет 10 не работал. Для git идея такая - прописать базовую прогу как remote и, когда она обновляется, делать pull.

Comment: Считаю этот вопрос вполне конкретным. Задача решается через форки или субмодули. Об этом можно написать хороший, конкретный и полезный ответ. Так что закрывать не нужно, нужно отвечать.

Answer (score 3):

Вынесите общий код в модули или библиотеки. Для каждого из них используйте свое дерево в svn или репозиторий в git. Соответственно в каждом из проектов подключаете эти модули или библиотеки средствами svn:external или git submodule. 
Изменения внутри этих библиотек будут синхронизироваться между проектами независимо от самих проектов.